# How do I season potato wedges or quartered roasted potatoes with 'Leon's Baked Fries'?

Tags: potatoes

From to right: [Leon's official website](http://leonrestaurants.co.uk/menu/all-day/menu-item/leon-baked-fries), [2](http://ot-foodspotting-production.s3.amazonaws.com/reviews/5538843/thumb_600.jpg?1439909642), [3](http://ot-foodspotting-production.s3.amazonaws.com/reviews/5902396/thumb_600.jpg?1470836147). [Google](https://www.google.com/search?q=leon%27s+baked+fries&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwig74aOzcvUAhUG2yYKHd5RA1U4ChD8BQgHKAI&biw=1152&bih=538#imgrc=_) has more images.

[image]

Clicking on "MORE" (as per the green arrow) unveils:

> Ingredients
>
> **Crisscut Fries** (Potatoes, Vegetable oil, Modified starch, Corn flour, Rice flour, Salt, Starch, Spices, Garlic powder, Onion powder, Raising agents: Sodium Bicarbonate, E450(i), Yeast extract, Spice extracts Thickener: Xanthan Gum, Dextrose),
> **Leon Seasoning** *(Spices (Paprika, Smoked Paprika, Coriander (ground), Black Pepper), Herbs (Rosemary, Thyme, Oregano), Dried Garlic, Sea Salt, Smoked Salt, Onion Powder*

1. Do I just mix the ingredients (hereafter IGT) in a bowl, and then  strew Leon's Seasoning  over baked potato wedges or quartered roasted potatoes? This  looks wrong, as the pictures above exhibit little seasoning on the fries.
2. If this is right, at what stage do I speckle?
3. Or must the mixed ingredients be in(ter)jected in the potatoes?

Answer (score 2):

Normally spices are added after frying the potatoes (fries, wedges...)

If you add the spices before frying, either they will fall off the potatoes or burn and turn bitter in the oil.

The spices are probably finely grounded (powered) so it is not really visible.

Comment: But if you bake your wedges, brushing with oil and sprinkling the spices (before or part way through) works well.